# Android - How to change Glide Transform smooth?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide

I used [glide-transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations) library for implement image processing
But this code not working smooth. The image disappears once and then reappears. Because of no caching for refresh image. I want change like this video - [brightness filter](https://youtu.be/wRSDash0cCE)
I want to show the change in the image while still changing the filter effect to the same image. 
So what should I do?

```
//for refresh, not use caching
val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
     .skipMemoryCache(true)

Glide.with(this@ImageProcessingActivity)
     .load(imageUri)
     .apply(requestOptions)
     .into(binding.imageView)

binding.imageProcessingCardViewBackground.setOnClickListener {
    testBrightness += 0.1f

    Glide.with(this@ImageProcessingActivity)
          .load(imageUri)
          .apply(bitmapTransform(MultiTransformation(BlurTransformation(5), BrightnessFilterTransformation(testBrightness)
     )))
    .apply(requestOptions)
    .into(binding.imageView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                .crossFade(300)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(view);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.

I tried this

val requestOptions = RequestOptions()
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)

    Glide.with(this@ImageProcessingActivity)
          .load(imageUri)
          .apply(bitmapTransform(MultiTransformation(BlurTransformation(5), BrightnessFilterTransformation(testBrightness)
     )))
    .apply(requestOptions)
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
    .into(binding.imageView)

However, the image is changed only once at the first time, and is not changed from the second time.